# Bicycles Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place.

If you're a bicycles.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Bicycles Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out to your fellow cyclists during local meetups or races.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: bicycles.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/email/phone are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL, etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: I think I like it.

Comment: It's a really nice idea, but I don't think I would personally use them. Since I'm on the board of [my local cycling advocacy organization](http://www.bikesonoma.org/), if I'm at a local cycling event I'm promoting that group.

Comment: Like @Freiheit I wonder how many people don't already have business cards for their cycle activism, or would use business cards if they don't already have them. I already carry cards for my day-job, geek-for-hire, bicycle advocate and a couple of other cards as it is. I also carry "it's a velomobile and blah de blah" cards that I give to the curious (and stupid). IMO to be useful it needs more information, not just say "I wish to make an argument from authority". OTOH, having one would be kinda cool as a souvenir.

Comment: I like it - I'm not on any local boards, and do have a day job card. I think it would come in handy occasionally, and might be useful as a marketing tool to drive traffic to the site.